# Server redirect does not work with ReactJS proxy server

Tags: reactjs, go, redirect, server, proxy

I'm using a proxy server on my react front end and a Go server for my back end.  When I DON'T use react or a proxy server, the redirect works fine.  But when I use react, with its development server and a proxy to my Go back end, the redirect doesn't do anything.

```
// React package.json file 
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000", // proxy to golang hosted on 5000
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
},

-----------------------

// golang server

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("../client/public", true)))
    ping := router.Group("/path") 
    ping.GET("/ping", pingFunc)
    ping.POST("/ping", pingFuncPost)
    router.Run(":5000")
}

// This redirect is not working.
// In the terminal it shows that a redirect is made but on the frontend
// nothing occurs

func pingFuncPost( c *gin.Context) 
{
    http.Redirect(c.Writer, c.Request, "/page", http.StatusSeeOther)`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You redirect, with

```
        const data = {"query": this.state.query};
        fetch(`/path/ping`, {  // should hit the end point of pingFuncPost in golang server, which should redirect to localhost:3000/results
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering.
So when I tried to send data back and *then* also send back the redirect, I got an error about overriding the headers. 
How would you recommend redirecting from the server only?

UPDATE
So I got the correct redirected url to come in through the Network tab on "inspect" within chrome.  But the frontend page isn't actually changing (the URL stays the same at the home page).  Do you know why that is?

Comment: No problem , glad I help! ;) So this is happening because your front end is in a different domain than your server, so the client can't redirect to the server, usually, you would talk to the front end with json from the server. To redirect to the server you have to have your front end rendered from the server. But I can help you with that, is kind hard to explain here, could you add your code in an online editor, that would be easier to explain, thank you ;)

Comment: Here's the link.
Thanks again!
https://codeshare.io/5eojOx 

So just in case it's not clear.  I have a search bar component.  Once a user submits their query, handleSubmit sends a post request back to the server, which hits the pingFuncPost endpoint and should redirect the user to the localhost:3000/results page but the page stays at the home page and doesn't move.

Comment: Are you familiar with single page applications and dynamic websites?

Comment: I can explain here, https://join.slack.com/t/tutoring-s6w8396/shared_invite/enQtNjIzNjIxOTg3Nzc2LWU4M2I0ODA3NDVjNmMyNWRkNzA3MDQwM2MwOWU5YWJjN2M4YWRkNDBjZTE1ZWI0ZWRjZTY2NzBiZjY1Yzg0MmU add the slack channel.

Comment: I edited the post with how you would redirect to another component ;) let me know if it helps!